# Is there any way in iOS to browse through Core Data objects from the Detail View, a function similar to "Notes" app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I can't find much info about this, so I don't know exactly where to start. What I'm trying to do is to add a UIButton on my Detail View, so that when I'll press it, it will load the next Core Data object from the Table View, something similar to the "Notes" app. Any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about the delegation pattern?

Make the master view controller a delegate of the detail view controller. When you press the "Next"-Button send a message to the delegate (your table view controller). The delegate will then setup the detail view with the next object.

I wouldn't add any code, that figures out which object is next, to the detail view controller. Your tableview controller has those methods already.

Comment: Agreed, we use a similar pattern for a list of comments, see https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS/blob/3.5.3/WordPress/Classes/CommentViewController.m#L412 and https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS/blob/3.5.3/WordPress/Classes/CommentsViewController.m#L601

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to perform a fetch request that fetches all of the objects you would like loaded in series. This won't actually fetch the data, but will 'fault' the objects. Faulting basically gives you a reference to a core data entity without actually retrieving that entity. Your request will return an NSArray that is sorted based on the sort descriptor you load into the fetch request object. You can then have a local property that tracks which index you currently are on in the NSArray and simply load the next object in the array whenever the UIButton is pressed. As you load the objects from the array, core data will automatically retrieve all of the attributes for that entity.

Answer (score 0):

If your model has a unique value that corresponds to each object in the tableView, you could load the object properties into an array of dictionaries in prepareForSegue and pass it to the detail view, making sure there is a one-to-one correspondence between the object at your indexPath.row and the array's objectAtIndex.

Ensure that you grab the index of the selected row in order to determine your position within the list, then you can traverse the array of dictionaries with each tap on the UIButton. If you need to do more than just populate the detail view, you can fetch the unique model object corresponding to each dictionary object.

It's not as clean as working with the original object but it gets around the faulting issue mentioned by MySpecialPurpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a delegate for your details view that asks it's master view what to do when the button is pressed (or simply to give the next item for a given item), which is the best solution in my opinion, or keep the list of model objects in a separate objects that both view controller can access and query. This is not a really good pattern though and doesn't really reflect the hierarchy of the views nor one of the key Object Oriented Programming rules: the least privilege one.